# What is the current best way to handle a CSS entry file in Webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

This should be simple, but I'm kind of stumped over how complex it's turning out to be.

What I would like to do is have a simple reference to my CSS in my Webpack config's entry list:

```
    entry: {
        'app.js': './src/app/index.js',
        'app.css': './src/app/app.css',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'web/[name]',
    },
```

app.css can import other files through the standard CSS syntax: `@import url('./morestuff.css');` I would like these to be inlined as Webpack does for JS imports.

I would like that to be exported as normal. For the config above that means outputting it into 'dist/web/app.css'.

I **don't** want:

- To import/require CSS in my JS
- To have it output a JS file that either includes the CSS as a string, or dynamically loads the CSS file itself
- To do any HTML rewriting

What I've tried/considered:

- Using [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) outputs JS instead of CSS.
- Using css-loader along with [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) will import/concat the files as I'd like, but the actual entrypoint output file is JS, and the CSS file it makes is in the wrong folder and renamed to `app.css.css`. If I try mini-css-extract-plugin without css-loader then it can't handle `@` characters (I think it's trying to load the file as JS.)
- Using the sequence of loaders `['file-loader', 'extract-loader', 'css-loader']` as indicated in the [extract-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/extract-loader/#extracting-a-maincss) documentation, but it behaves as above (except the CSS is output with a hashed filename.)
- Lots of old SO questions refer to [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), but that is now an archived project.
- [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) is about HTML rewriting, not what I want.

Now this may not be the "proper" way to handle CSS in Webpack, which does seem to be based on importing everything from your JS, but it's surely a common enough pattern. Any ideas?

Comment: What I ended up doing: use [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) instead!